# Iconos personalizados de tab salen muy pequeños

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buenos días

Tengo un tablayout que tienen unos iconos personalizados, estos tienen un selector que cuando es seleccionado se muestra un icono y cuando no está seleccionado se muestra otro icono.

Este es mi selector, el que hace que se muestra tal icono cuando es seleccionado y otro cuando no es seleccionado:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_consumo_selected"
      android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_consumo_unselected"/>
```

El ícono que aparece cuando es seleccionado es este **"circle_consumo_selected"**, este icono lo que hace es que se cree un circulo con una imagen dentro, el otro icono **"circle_consumo_unselected"** es lo mismo, solo que es otro fondo y otra imagen.

```
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
       <shape android:shape="oval">
         <solid android:color="@color/button_background"/>
      </shape>
  </item>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/iconsumos"
    android:bottom="25dp"
    android:left="18dp"
    android:right="13dp"
    android:top="25dp"/>
  </layer-list>
```

**Entonces mi problema es que los iconos funcionan correctamente pero salen demasiados pequeños, cómo haría para que salgan un poco más grandes?**

Les dejo la imagen de como se ven actualmente:

[image: Imagen actual de iconos del tab]

Answer (score 0):

Google recomienda guardes los iconos en la carpeta `mimap` y con sus respectivos tamaños para adaptarse a cada tamaño de pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la carpeta `drawable` las imágenes que deben tener las mismas 5 densidades ya mencionadas. Esto te ayudara a que tus iconos o imágenes no se vean pequeños y borrosos.

Puedes descargar iconos con sus 5 tamaños desde la [pagina de google](https://material.io/icons/#ic_account_circle) o realizar tus propios iconos a partir de tu imagen [aquí](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).

Comment: Sí tengo guardadas las densidades en el drawable, tengo guardado la imagen con sus respectivas densidades, también el circulo salen muy pequeños

Comment: dentro de tu XML debes configurar el tamaño dentro de tu item...

Comment: Felix @AshleyG. En el sitio ya se encuentra esta información porque no mejor orientar al usuario a encontrarla.

Comment: @Jorgesys esta enfocado de otra manera, el dilema no esta en el uso de las carpetas como comento ...